# TYPO3: How do I allow <video> tag inside the RTE editor?

Tags: php, html, video, typo3

I am not really familiar with TYPO3, but have been asked so insert some video into a TYPO3 website. However it doesent seem to allow the  tag. I tried to put it on the allow list in pageTSConfig.text inside proc folder. (I don't have acess to the TSconfig from the backend somehow ?)

How can I allow video tags ?

Comment: I don't know how to allow that tag in TYPO3.

But as a remark: don't do that – you will get only more problems.

Please mind, that the browser support for HTML5 multimedia tags is far from complete, so most web-developers make use of some JS library to enable playing of video. The problem here is, that most RTE scripts will implode if you try to execute another JS indide their editor object. In fact, most RTE-implementations replace the `VIDEO`- and `AUDIO`-tags with some placeholder-`DIV` (e.g. TinyMCE).

Comment: Thanks.. I ended up coding the whole thing external from TYPO3

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access the TSConfig, you should check if you can select the 'HTML' content type when creating a new content element. This allows you to put raw HTML which isn't processed further.